# Unbound Expression not calculating in runtime winforms devexpress?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I created gridview in runtime and attached data source in runtime. Created new column and assign Unbound Expression on that column. When i run this i got only empty column. Help me to solve this. 
This is my code

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT InvoiceId, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, Customername AS CustomerId, (Select CustomerName from Customer where Customer.CustomerId = NewInvoice_1.CustomerName) AS Customer_Name, Tax, GrandTotal, CompanyId, InvoiceStatus FROM NewInvoice_1 WHERE CompanyId=" + TXE_CompId.Text + " ", connection);
DataSet sourceDataSet = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(sourceDataSet);
gridControl1.DataSource = sourceDataSet.Tables[0];

gridView1.Columns.Add(new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn()
   {
       Caption = "Total",
       FieldName = "Total",
       VisibleIndex= 3 ,
       UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Decimal,
       UnboundExpression = "Round([GrandTotal] - [Tax]), 2)"
   });
```

This is my output screen
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look into the [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument6214)? `Round` method doesn't takes two argument.

It takes only one argument. Try this

```
UnboundExpression = "Round([GrandTotal] - [Tax])"
```

Comment: ha ha thinking deeply. Thanks a lot.